# In Java 8, can the method reference part of a call always be parenthesized?

Tags: java-8, overloading

Say I have a type correct Java method call, such as

```
f.g(5)
```

Java 8 now allows method references, so in most cases one can now write

```
(f::g)(5)
```

where `f::g` turns into a lambda function which is then called.

**Question**: Is this always possible even in cases where `f::g` is overloaded, or can overloading interfere with the two step process?  This would happen if the overload determination must happen at the level of the method reference, before the argument types are known.

Motivation: I am writing compiler-like code, which is why I need to understand these subtleties.  I am aware that parenthesizing method references in calls is not a necessary software engineering practice.

Comment: Note that your code example does not work in Java 8 as you have to specify a *target type* for the method reference. And it’s the target type which determines the type of the method reference, not the argument that you pass to the method invocation, e.g. `((DoubleConsumer)f::g).accept(5)`. The argument `5` does not add anything to the type inference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

However, I think you are confused about what this feature is.  The utterance of `f.g` in the above is not a method reference; it's not even an expression.

A method reference is an expression that looks like `Foo::bar` and can be converted to a functional interface type.

Comment: Apologies for the typos.  I've fixed it to `f::g` now.  Do you have any insight as to the question?

Comment: Still no.  In fact, not a semantically valid Java expression.

Comment: As to the secondary question about overloading: Method refs are divided into exact and inexact method references; exact refs are those that are not overloaded (so they can be given a type in a bottom-up analysis.)